# Charindex won't select the right character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to select a value that is contained inside two square brackets using a combination of Substring() and Charindex(), but my second instance of Charindex() will not work as advertised.

```
select substring([Attribute 11], CHARINDEX('[', [Attribute 11], 0) + 1, CHARINDEX(']', [Attribute 11], 0) - 1))
from Table1
where [Attribute 11] like '%]%'
```

The Charindex() for the starting position works fine and removes the first bracket with the +1 added after. However, the ending position - 1 does not work until I change it to - 19 (- 10 for another column). I've tried the Rtrim() and Ltrim() functions to no avail. When I copy the data, there does not seem to be any extra spaces anyway, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: You should show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the value `'Some [value] here'`, and that I **assume** you want the value `'value'`.

Firstly, `CHARINDEX('[', [Attribute 11], 0) + 1` will return the `7`, which is position+1 of the first `[` character.

Next you have `CHARINDEX(']', [Attribute 11], 0) - 1` which returns 11. That too is correct, as the character `]` is at posotion 12, and `12-1=11`.

Great, nothing wrong with the `CHARINDEX` expressions.

It *seems* you think that the 3rd paramter for `SUBSTRING` is ending position; it is not. A quick visit to [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will tell you it is **length** not end.

Therefore you have the `SUBSTRING` where you state you want the next **`11`** characters, starting at position `7`. That returns `'value] here'`. Therefore what you have written is working exactly as written. There is nothign wrong with `CHARINDEX` or `SUBSTRING` here.

What you instead likely want is this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Attribute 11], CHARINDEX('[', [Attribute 11], 0) + 1, CHARINDEX(']', [Attribute 11], 0) - CHARINDEX('[', [Attribute 11], 0) -1),
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE [Attribute 11] like '%]%';
```

Which, for my example value, would return `'value'`. This substracts the value of the first `CHARINDEX` from the second, resulting in getting the length of characters you want.